# Are "lassen" and "sich lassen", when used causatively, interchangeable?

Tags: grammar

What I mean by that is the following:

If I want to say, for instance, *He is having his car repaired*, I say in German, *Er läßt sein Auto reparieren*.

But can I say the same (*He is having his car repaired*) with *sich lassen* instead: *Er läßt sich sein Auto reparieren?*

Comment: I'd consider this as wrong but I wouldn't be surprised if this is common is some regions. I even must admit that I probably wouldn't notice if someone add *sich* in this sentence.

Comment: *Sie lässt sich die Haare schneiden* vs. *Sie lässt die Haare schneiden* - **brilliant question!**;)

Comment: Hahaha @Takkat. Brilliant example. For me it's "Sie lässt *sich* die Haare schneiden" but "Er lässt sein Auto reparieren".

Comment: eben darum ist die Frage ja so toll. ;)

Comment: @Takkat jeez, that was the first thing i thought of too ;)

Comment: Was ist causatively?

Comment: @Takkat: Vielen Männern ist das Auto so nah wie einer Frau das Haar. ;)

Comment: @user unknown: Deutsch _kausativ_. Es geht um _lassen_ in der (kausativen) Bedeutung „jemanden veranlassen, etwas zu tun“ (im Gegensatz z.B. zu „jemandem erlauben, etwas zu tun“).

Comment: @chirlu: Schade, Latein sprech ich noch viel weniger... :) - ich kenne nur `in der Kausa` bzw. den Kausalzusammenhang. Ah, Anlass ist hier das verbindende Element.

Answer (score 7):

No, they are not.

You lose - even if just a little - the completeness of definition.

> Er lässt *sich* die Haare schneiden.
>   vs.
>   Er lässt die Haare schneiden.

or

> Er lässt *sich* ein Auto reparieren
>   vs.
>   Er lässt ein Auto reparieren

You lose the definition of whose hair it is on the way. This only happens when using an article though:

> Er lässt *sich seine* Haare schneiden
>   vs.
>   Er lässt *seine* Haare schneiden.

Here you can clearly see it is *his* hair.
Above it is just hair. Whether it is *his* or *someone else's* cannot be known from the construction.

But when using a possessive article you can freely change them, even though I would prefer the non-redundant version (without another *sich*).

Comment: *"Er lässt sich seine Haare schneiden"* geht aber auch. Beim Auto hingegen funktioniert das nicht.

Comment: @Takkat ich würde meinen, dass das beim Auto sehr wohl geht... ich dachte, das mit dem *sich seine* ist überflüssig, weil impliziert...

Comment: Vielleicht hast Du recht... spannend!

Comment: @Takkat Then why is _Er lässt sich seine Haare schneiden_ correct, but not _Er läßt sich sein Auto reparieren_?

Comment: No idea, I just wouldn't say *"Morgen lasse ich mir mein Auto reparieren"* this sounds rather odd.

Comment: @indoxica You bring up a good point. I think in case of cut hairs you can say "sich seine" or "sich die" but it's somewhat odd to omit *sich*. When talking about car repair, you say "lässt sein", perhaps regionally "lässt sich sein" but definitely not "lässst sich ein" as currently in this answer. About why... Not sure yet.

Comment: @Em1 If you do find an authoritatively encoded grammatical explanation for this, please do tell me which this authoritatively encoded grammatical explanation is. For my goal is to master a divinely perfect German...

Comment: I disagree, it is possible to say "Er lässt sich ein Auto reparieren", but here it is no longer clear whose car it is or if he has a car fixed in order to buy it, but you can always say "Er lässt sich das Auto reparieren." This is prefectly idiomatic.

Comment: @Takkat: Ich lasse mir Winnetous Pferd bringen (um von den Autos loszukommen). Im Gegensatz zu meinem Pferd, welches ich Napoleon bringen lasse. Was ist da odd?

Comment: @userunknown Das ist wie Äpfel mit Birnen vergleichen. Und genau darauf zielt meine Antwort auch hinaus. Bei Autos und reparieren ist es "odd", bei Pferden und bringen ist es "OK", genau so wie bei Haaren und schneiden es "OK" ist. Wir können ja noch ein Beispiel hinzufügen: Kinder und abholen. "Ich lasse mir die Kinder von der Schule abholen" ist bullshit. Es ist "Ich lasse die Kinder von der Schule abholen." Achja, im Pferdbeispiel ohne "mir" fehlt eine wichtige Information. Wem bringt man es. Die Info fehlt nicht, wenn man die Kinder abholt oder das Auto repariert. Es ist implizit gegeben.

Comment: Frage ist nur, warum ist das so? Warum empfindet man es so? Hat glaub ich was mit dem Verb selbst zu tun. *Abholen* und *reparieren* erwarten keine Konkretisierung. *Bringen* dagegen schon. Du sagst "Bring mir das." und "Gib mir das" und nicht "Bring das" und nicht "Gib das", aber du sagst, "Reparier das" und "Hol die ab." und nicht "Reparier mir das" und "Hol mir die ab." You see?

Comment: It depends. Gib acht, Gib Gas sagt man durchaus. Offenbar lassen sich mancherorts die Leute aber zu einem `Gib mir acht auf die Frösche` hinreißen, wo in Landstrichen, in denen ich Deutsch gelernt habe, `Gib auf die Frösche acht` ohne `wem oder was` geflegt wird. `Es "OK" ist` ist übrigens selbst nicht OK, nicht ohne Anführungsstriche und erst recht nicht mit. "Reparier mir das" könnte ich durchaus sagen, wenn ich in eigener Kausa unterwegs bin, und nicht im Auftrag. Glaub mir das. :)

Comment: Wenn ein Werkstattbetreiber zu seinem Mechaniker sagt "Reparier das", handelt es sich wahrscheinlich um einen Kundenauftrag oder betrifft anderweitig das Geschäft. Sagt er aber "Reparier mir das", geschieht das in der Regel in seinem privaten Interesse. "Er lässt sich sein Auto reparieren" kann daher sinnvoll sein, wenn man ausdrücken will, dass er sich damit irgendeinen Vorteil verschafft (außer dem, dass das Auto danach wieder funktioniert).

Answer (score 4):

Usually the reflexive use and the transitive use are not interchangeable, obviously.

But here we have the special case that both possessive pronouns `sich` and `sein` have identical reference. So one of the possessive pronouns can be dropped without creating ambiguity, but there is nothing wrong in using both side by side.

Answer (score 3):

*Sich lassen* means *to allow something* or *to make something happen* (in German *zulassen*, *erlauben*, *veranlassen*).

The following sentences are all grammatically fine. Just note that they not idiomatic German.

> Ich lasse zu, dass mein Auto repariert wird.
> Ich erlaube, dass mein Auto repariert wird.
> Ich veranlasse, dass mein Auto repariert wird.
>
> Ich lasse zu, dass meine Haare geschnitten werden.
> Ich erlaube, dass meine Haare geschnitten werden.
> Ich veranlasse, dass meine Haare geschnitten werden.

Having said that, actually the following constructions are fine:

> sich seine Haare schneiden lassen
> sich sein Auto reparieren lassen

While it's idiomatic to say the first one indeed,

> Ich gehe morgen zum Friseur und lasse mir die Haare schneiden.
> Du musst dir mal wieder die Haare schneiden lassen.
> Er lässt sich von seiner Tante die Haare schneiden.

the second is rather uncommon. As already mentioned in my comments I guess you'll hear "sich sein Auto reparieren lassen" though, and I probably wouldn't notice an additional *sich* in most instances. However, the 'correct' sentences should be:

> Er hat <strike>sich</strike> sein Auto von seinem Onkel reparieren lassen.
> Er lässt <strike>sich</strike> sein Auto immer nur von der KFZ-Fachwerkstatt reparieren. <sub>[gemeint ist damit eine Werkstatt, die auf einen bestimmten Fahrzeugtyp spezialisiert ist, zum Beispiel Ford, VM, BMW]</sub>

I cannot give any answer on **why**, but what I can say for sure that you **should not add** *sich* if you use a definite or indefinite article.

> Er lässt ein/das Auto reparieren.

This sentence is absolutely fine without the reflexive pronoun. But it's not correct to say:

> *Er lässt sich ein/das Auto reparieren.

In case of using *das* it's already clear from context which car you're talking about. In case of *ein* it's not yet clear but an additional *sich* does **not add any information**. The necessary information will likely be given later.

See these two examples:

> A: Der Meier fährt zwei Autos. Er lässt sich ein Auto reparieren. Ich weiß aber nicht, welches.
>
> A: Der Meier lässt <strike>sich</strike> ein Auto reparieren.
> B: Seit wann fährt er denn ein Auto?
> A: Tut er nicht. Seine Sohnemann ist aber mit dem Fahrrad in des Nachbars Auto geknallt.

I guess it's obvious that *sich* is wrong in the second sentence. But you also see that there's no further information if you add *sich* in the first example. The usage of *sich* is just weird in both cases.

If you wanna know my opinion, you'll find the answer back in history. It's just developed that way. **I don't agree** that the issue **is about redundant information**. Again, compare those two instances and their different usages:

> Er lässt die Haare schneiden. [Very rare at best, no explicit information at all but..]
>
> Er lässt die Haare schneiden. – Welche? – Natürlich seine.  <sub>Some people would even give you a sarcastic comment if you would ask such an ignorant question.</sub>
>
> Er lässt sich die Haare schneiden. [No redundancy, and (probably most) common]
>
> Er lässt sich seine Haare schneiden. [Redundant, but very common though]
>
> Er lässt sein Auto reparieren. [No redundancy, and common]
>
> Er lässt ein Auto reparieren. [No information at all, and very rare in use]
>
> Er lässt sich sein Auto reparieren. [Redundancy, but not common anyways]
>
> Er lässt sich ein Auto reparieren. [No redundancy; actually somewhat wrong, not in use anyways]

Comment: You make some good points, but I find this post quite confusing, it mixes grammatical and semantical level quite freely. And what about your opening statement "Sich lassen means to allow something" - that is downright wrong, could you edit that? Your reference to "zulassen" including the examples also seems to be misleading, imho.

Comment: @bouscher "jemanden etwas machen lassen" means that you allow to do something. E.g. "Ich lasse mich nicht an der Nase herumführen" means that I don't allow anyone to 'play games with me' (if this is idiomatic English).

Comment: It is true, that there is an overlap in meaning, but as in English, there is a shade of differenc between "let-lassen" and "allow-erlauben". The later involves active permission, whereas "Ich lasse mich fallen", "ich lasse mich überzeugen", "ich lasse mich überraschen" have to do with abandonment, surrender. "Ich erlaube, mich zu überraschen" is not quite the same as "Ich lasse mich überraschen", is it?

Comment: Or to take your example: "Ich erlaube nicht, mich an der Nase herumzuführen" is not interchangeable with "Ich lasse mich nicht an der Nase herumführen", or would you say it is?

Comment: @bouscher Of course it's not equally. Otherwise it would be synonymous. Otherwise the examples in the beginning would likely be idiomatic. My point is, that this is the idea behind it, kinda of implicit meaning. Btw. the German words I enumerated I'd taken from the Duden definition and I just translated them.

Comment: That's why I find your post a bit confusing, when you mean differently, why not say so: "sich lassen means let oneself", to any native English speaker this would be much more clarifying, I guess, than bringing connotations in, without giving reason why.

Comment: Or at least the form should be congruent: "Lassen means to allow something". ("sich lassen" heißt ja auch nicht "etwas erlauben")

Comment: But my main problem with the post is, that you seem to try to explain the issue by giving all possible/impossible combinations. I don't think that's a viable way.

Comment: I swear I had no idea, when I asked this question, what an interesting, if open, debate, it would stir...

Comment: @bouscher Actually the reason I did this is because I don't agree with both answers, yours and Vogel612's. I, however, cannot really provide an answer either. I just want to show that's it's more complex than it appears on first glance.

Comment: @Em1: `Er lässt ein Auto reparieren.` dürfte überall, wo ein Fuhrpark existiert (Firma, Polizei, Bundeswehr, ...) oft der Fall sein, ohne dass derjenige, der es veranlasst, der Eigentümer ist. `Er läßt sich sein Auto reparieren` ist keine Redundanz, denn wenn ich das Auto meines Bruders leihe, und es im Urlaub reparieren lasse, weil die Scheibe rausgefallen ist, dann lasse ich mir sein, nicht mein Auto reparieren, aber mir und nicht ihm, weil ich es noch weiter nutzen will, bevor ich es ihm zurückgebe.

Comment: @Em1 Dein Unterfangen ist ehrenwert, aber ich glaube nicht, dass wir hier in der Lage sein werden, sämtliche Bedeutungsvarianten zu erschlagen, da es potenziell unendlich viele gibt. Ansonsten gleicht das hier dem Versuch, die komplette semantische Struktur des Deutschen herzuleiten. Es handelt sich hier überhaupt nicht um einen Spezialfall. Wir haben alle Ingredienzien um Amibguität oder Disambiguität herzustellen: reflexiv/transitiv, bestimmte/unbestimmte Artikel, Quantoren, besitzanzeigende Fürwörter...

Comment: @userunknown Nitpicking. Bitte, lass es sein! Ja, ohne Kontext könnte "sein" doppeldeutig sein, aber es ist doch eindeutig, was ich meine. Und wenn ich das Auto meines Bruder reparieren lassen will, dann sage ich "Ich lasse das Auto meines Bruders reparieren" und nicht "Ich lasse mir sein Auto reparieren". Nein, nein und nochmals NEIN!

Comment: @bouscher Nochmals, meine Intention war nur zu zeigen, dass es nicht so simple ist, wie in den anderen Antworten angedeutet wird. Und wie gesagt, ich bin auch nicht in der Lage eine richtige Antwort darauf zu geben. Ich habe die Antwort bewusst "CW" gemacht. Sie ist nur eine Hilfestellung, das Problem zu verstehen.

Comment: @Em1: Was bist Du denn so empfindlich? Ob Du sagst "meines Bruders" oder "sein" hängt ja wohl davon ab, ob unmittelbar zuvor von Deinem Bruder die Rede war - wenn nicht kannst Du natürlich nicht "sein" sagen. Du kannst zwar auch sonst "das Auto meines Bruders" statt "sein" sagen, aber es ist doch kein Grund dreifach "Nein" in die Mittagssonne zu brüllen!